# Python filename from path with \

Tags: python

I have a list of paths that looks like this `C:/Users/myuser/Documents/files\my_file_1.csv` and I want to get the file name from that by doing this:

```
path=['C:/Users/myuser/Documents/files\my_file_1.csv','C:/Users/myuser/Documents/files\my_file_2.csv',...]

filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(path[0])
```

and I always get `'C:/Users/myuser/Documents/files\my_file_1'` I know it must be for the ' \ ' slash but I haven't been able to replace it. Can anyone give me an idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `os.path.basename` to get just the filename without the full directory, then `os.path.splitext` to remove the file extension.

```
>>> import os
>>> [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(i))[0] for i in path]
['my_file_1', 'my_file_2']
```

Or if you want the filename and extension, but no directories

```
>>> [os.path.basename(i) for i in path]
['my_file_1.csv', 'my_file_2.csv']
```

Comment: Super fast answer +1. I had done the same. But credits for speed

Comment: surely for `p` in path?  ;-)

Comment: @thebjorn I use `i` for "i've run out of coffee, and therefore good variable names for the day" :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using windows and if you are using python 3.4+

```
>>> from pathlib import PureWindowsPath
>>> path=['C:/Users/myuser/Documents/files\my_file_1.csv','C:/Users/myuser/Documents/files\my_file_2.csv']
>>> print([PureWindowsPath(i).name for i in path])
['my_file_1.csv', 'my_file_2.csv']
```